# Spring communication between context

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, events

I need to send a message/event from a bean manage by the rootContext to a bean manage by the mvcContext.

My webapp is composed of :
- the RootContext (applicationContext) : database, dao beans, services beans, security, etc
- a mvc-context (servlet entry in web.xml) : manage controllers, restcontroller and endpoint (websocket)

Each time a new row is created (in the service bean) I need to broadcast to all active websocket sessions.

I use ApplicationEventPublisherAware in the service bean to publish an event and @EventListener in the destination bean to handle it : but the event is not broadcasted outside the rootContext.

If I move the service bean in the mvcContext, it's ok
But I need the service bean in the rootContext because another component use it (other servlet (servlet entry in web.xml) ; spring-batch task ; etc...)

What should I do ?

PS : sorry for the bad english

Comment: Correct because the parent knowns nothing about child contexts. The other way around will work. You can create a bean in your child that registers as an `ApplicationListener` to the root context and then propagates events to the child context.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. But what the best way between register the service bean in the child context too or implement ApplicationListener in the child context and propagates events ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bean in the child context that registers itself as a listener to the parent context and on receipt of an event, republish it to the child context.

```
public class ContextBridgingApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener, ApplicationEventPublisherAware, ApplicationContextAware, SmartInitializingSingleton {

    private ApplicationContext context;
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    public void afterSingletonsInstantiated() {
        ApplicationContext parent = context.getParent();
        if (parent != null && parent instanceof ConfigurableApplicationContext) {
            ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) parent).addApplicationListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent evt) {
        this.publisher.publishEvent(evt);
    }

    // Setters ommitted

}
```

Haven't tested it, typed it down more or less from the top of my head. But putting this bean in the child context, should enable it to receive events from the parent and broadcast them to the child context.

**Note:** *There might be one flaw with this and that is that you might get caught in an event loop. As the child publishes to the parent again. So you might need a solution for that* ....

Comment: This solution will cause `java.lang.StackOverflowError` because child context will send event to parent context -> parent context send to child context -> child context send to parent .....

Comment: Sorry, I missed that :D